# While Loop in MySQL to select data with join and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I am beginner in MYSQL and I want to use while loop to get the data from the table using a select statement and joining another table via subquery.

Please help me guide to construct my code, Below is the code I've written but there's always an error

```
DECLARE cn INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tb INT DEFAULT 0;
SET tb = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(exam_id)) FROM mais_writtenworks_detail);

WHILE cn <= tb DO
    SELECT ms.`first_name`,ms.`middle_name`, ms.`last_name`, rr.ww_score
    FROM mais_students ms
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT mwd.ww_score, mwd.`student_id`
        FROM mais_writtenworks_detail mwd
        WHERE mwd.`exam_id`= cn
        ) AS rr ON (ms.`ID`= rr.`student_id`)
        
    SET cn = cn + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Here is the table

[image]

I tried this approach, but the exam_id is dynamic so I want to use loop

[image]

I need your help guys,

Comment: There is no reason for the loop. In fact any time you are working with a database (or any set based logic like a python Dataframe, as another example) and you think "I need a loop" you are headed in the wrong direction. I believe the SQL statement inside the loop will work as-is, just running it once, if you remove that `WHERE mwd.exam_id= cn` from the subquery.

Comment: And just to further clarify. Your `exam_id` is not dynamic. You, according to your loop logic, want to return a record for each `exam_id` where the studen exists in the `mais_students` table. So just don't add the where clause in the subquery and you will get what you are after.

Comment: Hello @JNevill, that's a wonderful answer. Thank you so much for your insights.  The result after deleting the WHERE clause, the values from the second exam_id appends at the bottom of the table, It needs to be in a new column besides the values of the first exam_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking [procedurally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming). But SQL is, unlike most other programming languages, [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). You describe the set of things you want and the server gives them to you.

I believe this is what you want. You don't need to muck around with a stored procedure to get this.

```sql
SELECT ms.ID, ms.`first_name`,ms.`middle_name`, ms.`last_name`, 
       mwd.exam_id, mwd.ww_score
  FROM mais_students ms
  LEFT JOIN mais_writtenworks_detail mwd
          ON mwd.student_id = ms.ID
 ORDER BY ms.ID, mwd.exam_id
```

You'll get a result set with one row per student per exam.

If you want to have two separate columns for two different exams, you must do a so-called [pivot](/questions/tagged/pivot) operation on the result set.  Like this.

```sql
SELECT ID, first_name, middle_name, last_name,
       MAX(IF(exam_id = 1, ww_score, null)) exam_1,
       MAX(IF(exam_id = 2, ww_score, null)) exam_2
  FROM (
         SELECT ms.ID, ms.`first_name`,ms.`middle_name`, ms.`last_name`, 
                mwd.exam_id, mwd.ww_score
           FROM mais_students ms
           LEFT JOIN mais_writtenworks_detail mwd
                    ON mwd.student_id = ms.ID
      ) detail
 GROUP BY ID, first_name, middle_name, last_name
 ORDER BY ID
```

Pivoting is a notorious pain in the xxx neck in SQL.